# What is your suggestion for defining this VOIP web-service?

Tags: web-services, routes, architecture, voip, naming

What is your suggestion about defining routes for such a web-service?

```
Input:
  called number
  call date
Output:
  caller number
  call datetime
  call duration
  call status
```

It is the first request for a web-service on a complete VOIP system database (including CDR, forwarding policies, ...) to deliver services to external and internal applications.

So, my question is how to design further extendable web-service routes according to best practices? For example:

```
/getCalls?calledNumber=&callDate=
```

or

```
/get/calls/to/{calledNumber}/{callDate}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I implemented it this way:

```
GET https://voip-api-server/calls?called-number=&call-date=
```

The operation name (here: get) should not appear in the URI. All VOIP read requests should use GET method.

It can be extended further by adding more filter parameters such as fromDate, toDate, callerNumber, ... .

All CDR requests (and other call related services) reside in /calls.

I avoided multi-word names like calledNumber using dash characters in the URI.